# Make a list of python pairs of two columns from dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, ggpairs

I have pandas dataframe

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : [a, b, c, d], 'y' : [e, f, g, h]})
```

I need to get from string  like this:

```
(first_element_from_first_row,first_element_from_second_row),
(second_element_from_first_row,second_element_from_second_row),
................................................................
(last_element_from_first_row,last_element_from_second_row);
```

at the end should be semicolon.

in my case the answer should be:

```
(a,e),(b,f),(c,g),(d,h);
```

How should I solve my problem?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly- you want to apply the following transformation:

you can use zip to iterate over each element of column "x" and column "y" at the same time as a tuple of elements. You can join those elements so that they are a string and wrap that in parentheses to get the desired row-wise output. Then you store all of those in a larger list and turn that larger list into a string separated by commas, and add a semicolon at the end.

```
all_pairs = []

for pair in zip(df_1["x"], df_1["y"]):
    pair_str = "({})".format(",".join(pair))
    all_pairs.append(pair_str)

final_str = ",".join(all_pairs) + ";"

print(final_str)
'(a,e),(b,f),(c,g),(d,h);'
```

Comment: Yours is the fastest implementation tested.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x' : ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'y' : ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})

ans = ""
for i in range(df_1.shape[0]):
    ans += '(' + df_1['x'][i] + ',' + df_1['y'][i] + '),'
    
ans = ans[:-1] + ';'

ans
'''
'(a,e),(b,f),(c,g),(d,h);'
'''
```

This is a pretty crude way but hey it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Convert to tuples.

```
s = ''.join(str([tuple(t) for _, t in df_1.iterrows()])) + ';'
```

If you want to strip the brackets and the spaces:

```
import re
s_new = re.sub(r'[\[\] ]', '', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65634850/7758804) from [Cameron Riddell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14278448/cameron-riddell) is the fastest tested, at 337 ms for 400k rows.
- My solution using a list-comprehension with `.map(tuple)` is the second fastest, at 391 ms for 400k rows

### sample data

```py
import pandas as pd

# test data
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'y': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})
```

- These two options are faster than using `.to_string()`

```py
','.join([f'{v}' for v in (df_1.x + df_1.y).map(tuple).values]) + ';'

','.join([f'{v}' for v in (df_1.sum(axis=1)).map(tuple).values]) + ';'
```

- My original assumption was these two options would be fastest, because they don't use a loop or list comprehension, but apparently, `.to_string()` is relatively slow.
- Either with the entire dataframe, or using `.loc` to specify columns, use `.sum(axis=1)`, map the sum to a `tuple`, and output to a `str` with `.to_string(index=False)`.

  - This results in `'(a, e)\n(b, f)\n(c, g)\n(d, h)'` so `\n` is replaced with `,`.

```py
# use .loc to specify specific columns
df_1.loc[:, ['x', 'y']].sum(axis=1).map(tuple).to_string(index=False).replace('\n', ',') + ';'

# use this option to sum all columns
df_1.sum(axis=1).map(tuple).to_string(index=False).replace('\n', ',') + ';'
```

```
# resulting output of each
'(a, e),(b, f),(c, g),(d, h);'
```

### `%%timeit`

```py
# sample data with 400k rows
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'y': ['e', 'f', 'g', 'h']})
df = pd.concat([df_1] * 100000).reset_index(drop=True)

# Cameron
%%timeit -r1 -n1 -q -o
cameron(df)
[out]:
<TimeitResult : 337 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)>

# Trenton
%%timeit -r1 -n1 -q -o
','.join([f'{v}' for v in (df.sum(axis=1)).map(tuple).values]) + ';'
[out]:
<TimeitResult : 391 ms ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)>

# xxdil
%%timeit -r1 -n1 -q -o
xxdil(df)
[out]:
<TimeitResult : 5.36 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)>

# ifly6
%%timeit -r1 -n1 -q -o
re.sub(r'[\[\] ]', '', ''.join(str([tuple(t) for _, t in df.iterrows()])) + ';')
[out]:
<TimeitResult : 34.8 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)>

# Trenton
%%timeit -r1 -n1 -q -o
df.sum(axis=1).map(tuple).to_string(index=False).replace('\n', ',') + ';'
[out]:
<TimeitResult : 49.6 s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)>
```

### Functions

```py
def cameron(df_1):
    
    all_pairs = []

    for pair in zip(df_1["x"], df_1["y"]):
        pair_str = "({})".format(",".join(pair))
        all_pairs.append(pair_str)

    return ",".join(all_pairs) + ";"


def xxdil(df_1):
    ans = ""
    for i in range(df_1.shape[0]):
        ans += '(' + df_1['x'][i] + ',' + df_1['y'][i] + '),'

    return ans[:-1] + ';'
```